# Tor error "DNS resolving failed"

Tags: dns

Tor is last version. When paste any .onion address I see this:

```
ERROR: Not Found
```

While trying to retrieve the URL http://site.onion/ (normal onion address, that actually works fine):

```
DNS resolving failed
```

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

What to do? Help please. Thanks.

Logs:

```
11/3/19, 16:35:55.949 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected 
to a relay 
11/3/19, 16:35:56.810 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay 
11/3/19, 16:35:56.820 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done 
11/3/19, 16:35:56.820 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits 
11/3/19, 16:35:56.820 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits 
11/3/19, 16:35:56.830 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit 
11/3/19, 16:35:56.952 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done 
11/3/19, 16:35:57.966 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
11/3/19, 17:15:50.185 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
11/3/19, 17:15:52.941 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
11/3/19, 17:15:52.941 [NOTICE] Rate limiting NEWNYM request: delaying by 8 second(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Onion services come and go quickly. It is no surprise that many of the ones that you might use are not functional. If you want to test your connection, a couple of ones that you can try are: [facebook](https://facebookcorewwwi.onion) and the [tor project](http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion).

Comment: Site I want to visit is online and working.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the error message:

> Your cache administrator is webmaster.

Suggests that whatever you're pasting the onion address into is configured to use a caching proxy that does not understand onion addresses.  You'll need to reconfigure your system to use a proxy that understands onion addresses, or to not use a proxy for connecting to onion addresses.

Comment: But I did not configured anything. Which way too look?